# Nesting arrays in LiveCode $_SESSION

Tags: arrays, session, livecode

I am developing a LiveCode Server CGI system that acts as a client web portal for an insurance business, by this I mean the client will log in and be able to see a whole host of information about their account. They'll be able to see their policy history, details of cover and download insurance certificates etc.

The basics are currently in place, clients can log in and the system connects to the database and pulls back their data.

HOWEVER, I would like to pre-load most of the important data during log in. For this I'm loading the data into $_SESSION, which works wonderfully for the basic user data (company name etc.)

As soon as I try to store an array of data in $_SESSION it simply doesn't work (e.g. data about each of their policies). If I store this data in a global array variable it works fine for the very next page loaded but it doesn't persist for the rest of the session.

Code below for loading the data from the DB

```
//load client info
put $_SESSION ["username"] into var1
put "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_number_display_text_c = :1" into tQuery
put revQueryDatabase(tDatabaseID, tQuery, "var1") into tCursor

put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "_pk_client") into $_SESSION["pk_client"]
put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "client_account_status") into $_SESSION["account_status"]
put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "client_category_aec") into $_SESSION["category"]
put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "client_display_name_c") into $_SESSION["display_name_c"]

//load policy info
put $_SESSION["pk_client"] into var1
put "SELECT * FROM policy WHERE " & quote & "_fk_client" & quote & " = :1" into tQuery
put revQueryDatabase(tDatabaseID, tQuery, "var1") into tCursor

if tCursor is an integer then
   put 1 into i

   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "_fk_broker") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["fk_broker"]
   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "_pk_policy") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["pk_policy"]
   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "policy_date_expiry_actual_aec") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["actual_expiry_date"]
   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "policy_date_inception_aec") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["inception_date"]
   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "policy_display_cover_products_c") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["display_products_c"]
   put revDatabaseColumnNamed(tCursor, "policy_total_price_inc_tax_admin_c") into $_SESSION["policies"][i]["total_price_inc_tax_admin_c"]
end if
```

(I'll be using a loop to read all the policy data in once I get this bit working, hence the 'i' variable)

When displaying the main screen I then use the code

```
put "<tr>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["display_products_c"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["inception_date"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["actual_expiry_date"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["total_price_inc_tax_admin_c"] & "</td>"
put "</tr>"
```

This simply displays a blank table row. I've tried putting $_SESSION into an array and using Combine but I simply get the top level data and nothing from the nested array

As a test I tried the following code

```
put "<tr>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["display_name_c"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["inception_date"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["actual_expiry_date"] & "</td>"
put "<td>" & $_SESSION["policies"][1]["total_price_inc_tax_admin_c"] & "</td>"
put "</tr>"
```

In this case the Client's Display Name shows the correct data in the first column - all other columns are blank.

I have used exactly the same code but instead of $_SESSION I simply use gUser (defined as global gUser). When using gUser in place of S_SESSION all data displays exactly as expected - but doesn't persist.

It appears as though $_SESSION isn't able to store nested arrays. If this is the case then I'll simply store a text list of keys (cr delimited probably) in $_SESSION["policy_keys"] - and then use AJAX to load the data on the fly when needed. So I'm aware there are ways around it, but I thought I'd ask before making further changes.

I'm using LiveCode Server 8.1.2, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Any help and guidance is most welcome

Answer (score 3):

First of all: sessions are usually stored in flat files so you will probably not gain much (if anything) by storing a lot of data in the session. Secondly if you have a heavy traffic site it might inflict performance and memory issues on your server.

Apart from that I have no idea why you shouldn't be able to save multidimensional arrays in a session, maybe it is saved in some specific way (maybe someone from the mothership can answer that). But here is a method I used a lot for sending "arrays" over the internet. I have no server reachable now so I can't test it for your specific case. But here goes the theory...

What you could try is to first create your array that you would like to save in a session and then use arrayEncode to store it in a session variable. Then you would at least get a flat session array:

```
put "data1" into tArr["key1"]
put "data2" into tArr["key2"]
...
put arrayEncode(tArr) into $_SESSION["myArray"]
```

Then retrieving the array will be the opposite:

```
put arrayDecode($_SESSION["myArray"]) into tArr
```

If $_SESSION doesn't like binary data (arrayEncode creates binary data) you can add another layer of encoding by using base64encode / -decode to ensure that you only save standard ascii codes. This is what I have done when sending arrays from one app to another over the net.

```
put base64Encode(arrayEncode(tArr)) into $_SESSION["myArray"]
put arrayDecode(base64Decode($_SESSION["myArray"])) into tArr
```

But again I'm not sure you will benefit at all by saving a lot of data into a session as I guess it is faster to repopulate from the DB.

If you build a really complex array based on several different tables in the database and you can't create a single select statement that will retrieve all your data again another solution might be to store your array in a single table using the above method. But I strongly suggest that you do some speed tests before you dive into a lot of extra programming...